# mongodb query watch

Tags: mongodb

Is there a tool I can use for mongodb to look at current and common queries?

I need to get this information to see what are the queries used most in order to build indexes efficiently.

Any help? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you done all the examples listed here http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/administration/monitoring/ ?

Namely, system.profile examination .

Comment: Yeah, their site is hard to navigate.